# Poverty and Islam: should we accept being poor?

Tags: politics

I was talking with my friend last time about poverty in the world and he said: "Allah gives what he wants to who he wants, we should just accept that". But if someone exploits another via employment shouldn't we say that it shouldn't be accepted according to Islam? Also shouldn't we all live equally if the laws of Islam are applied?

Comment: What do you mean by "exploits another via employment"?

Comment: Good question @goldPseudo, I mean we should be equal in Islam, so the salary I should have should be the same as my employer. But that's not what we see, thus the term: "exploits another via employement"

Comment: @bour we should be equal in Islam by other means, salary is distributed based on our efforts. It's also true some employers do not pay fair. But it's not true all should get the same salary.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this verse 11:6 Allah provisions all creatures. But it doesn't mean poverty. Allah wants us to go out of the house for making money for our households from Halal ways. We have many Hadiths which show that how we can make our provision more and by what sins our provision goes less.

*I couldn't find the related Hadith in English. But I will put the reference once I could find.*

Comment: But if someone wins just a little? Shouldn't we all live equally according to islam?

Comment: We are not the same in Zuhd and destiny, So how could live equally? In a Hadith, Amir al-Mo'menin said that Allah will examine people with less provision and high provision, and beside this As I mentioned some sins make our provision less!!

Comment: That is different, even if our destiny and Zuhd is different we could live equally by union and helping each other.

Comment: We are forbidden to live like the kings but we don't have anything that tell us to live equally!! But we have many statements that tell that the Muslim governors must live like the lowest class of the society!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ALLAH doesn't want us to be poor and wait the help from others. In the hadith

> المؤمن القوي خير من المؤمن الضعيف
>
> The strong believer is better than a weak believer

So ALLAH asked us to have contentment, but this doesn't mean that we sit in home and says ALLAH wants that. Absolutely NO, we have to learn and work as harder as we can and then whatever the result we should be pleased.

Also ALLAH is just and equitable but this doesn't mean that all of us should have the same salary. Everyone should take the salary he deserves according to his studies, tries and work.

But ALLAH ask us to help others. So for that we have to pay zakat and khoms and alms and this money will be distributed for poor people in some laws explained... If this is done we'll have no poverty in Islamic societies.

In short, Islamic rules make sure that nobody will be poor but this doesn't mean all of us should have the same salary and this doesn't mean we should stay at home and ask ALLAH for help.

Answer (score 0):

First, Islam does encourage you to seek *rizq* (sustenance), and while we do accept what Allah gives us that does not mean that we should just do nothing.

> "O Messenger of Allah! Shall I tie it and rely(upon Allah), or leave
> it loose and rely(upon Allah)?" He said: "Tie it and rely(upon
> Allah)."
>
> [Jami' At-termidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/727020)

Never in Islam has it been deemed that all people should have the same amount of fortune. Allah gives to some but not to others:

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The poor
> Emigrants came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: "The wealthy
> have gone with the highest ranks and lasting bliss." He asked: "How is
> that?" They replied: "They offer Salat (prayer) as we offer it; they
> observe fast as we do; (and as they are wealthy) they perform Hajj and
> 'Umrah, and go for Jihad, and they spend in charity but we cannot, and
> they free the slaves but we are unable to do so." The Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) said, "Shall I not teach you something with which you may
> overtake those who surpassed you and with which you will surpass those
> who will come after you? None will excel you unless he who does which
> you do." They said: "Yes, please do, O Messenger of Allah" He (ﷺ)
> said, "You should recite: Tasbih (Allah is free from imperfection),
> Takbir (Allah is Greatest), Tahmid (Praise be to Allah) thirty-three
> times after each Salat."
>
> [Narrated by Bukhari and Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1418)
>
> Muslim added to the narration: the poor Emigrants returned to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: "Our brother with wealth have heard of what we did, and they did the same?" and the Messenger of Allah said: "That is Allah's grace, which he gives to those He wishes to."